# Splitting the body of a post request into variables

Tags: http, post

I'm writing code, which takes the raw body of the post request (from a form, basically) and splits it into variables. Then it does some recoding on them and spits out the recoded post body back to output.

My question is if I can safely assume that splitting the body by the "&" character and then by "=" on the elements of the resulting array will get me variable names and values. Or are there some escape sequences which could possibly make my code produce nonsense on the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe, if `enctype` of the form is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (default value)

Reference:

[HTML 4.01 Specification - Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)

[RFC1738](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/references.html#ref-RFC1738)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You must also to ignore HTML entities, like `&nbsp;` (character), `&#160;` (numeric) and `&#x20;` (hexadecimal) which could be sent.</strike>

An HTML entity starts with a `&` and ends with a `;`

Sorry, with a well encoded form, I just realized you'll never stop by those characters. It's safe to split by `&` and `=`